# Conditionals and outputting tables

Tags: entry, conditional, table

Need a hand on a conditional to see if my table has any data, and if it does, output the table. The second thing I  need help is the code to output the table. When I look at tutorials, they always seem to output the table as an HTML list. Like:

```
   {% if block.codePoints | length %}
    <ul>
    {% for row in block.codePoints %}
         {# Assuming 'text' is the column handle of the text field #}
        <li>{{ row.text }}</li> 
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

I can't find an example of:

```
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is `block` a Matrix block?  If so, what type of field is `codePoints`?  Or is `block` the name of an entry and `codePoints` is a table field?

Comment: I'm unclear about the example code. It isn't my code but what I found on Stack Exchange. I just used it as an example. I can't seem to find an example to output a table using <table> mark-up. And also need to check to see if table is blank. Each table has 1 row of blank so my condition is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your example code, something along these lines will help...

```
{% if entry.yourTable | length %}
    <table>
    {% for row in entry.yourTable %}
    <tr>
       <td>{{ row.column1 }}</td><td>{{ row.column2 }}</td><td>{{ row.column3 }}</td>
    </tr> 
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endif %}
```

Here's the relevant section in the docs: [Table fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/table-fields#templating)